# VOD cache using Exoplayer 2.2

Tags: android, caching, okhttp, exoplayer

After doing some workarround on caching the Video/Audio content using exoplayer,i feel like the answer given here by Jacek [Using cache in ExoPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700391/using-cache-in-exoplayer) is the proper way to implement the caching for unbounded range requests instead of using the inbuilt Exocache supported by https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/420 & https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/57.
But he hasn't said anything on configuring the OkHttp & caching the request.

Can any one provide me some links on how to configure the okhttp & caching the request.

Comment: I got same problem you are facing.. not getting any official document or example to configured okhttp caching.

Comment: @comeback4you so how have done the caching for the VOD?

Comment: yet not, still finding

Comment: Can you put some light how you are trying to cache video content @comeback4you

Comment: I tried https://github.com/saeednt/ExoCacheDataSource but ExtractorSampleSource class not found in library.

Comment: @comeback4you the ExtractorSampleSource file wont be available for exoplayer higher version...it is available in 1.5 version of exoplayer...please check

Comment: add me on skype : live:thackerronak

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138198/discussion-between-pranesh-sahu-and-comeback4you).

Answer (score 0):

By making buildDataSourceFactory configuration change as below we can cache the video content

```
  private DataSource.Factory buildDataSourceFactory(final boolean useBandwidthMeter) {
//    return new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, useBandwidthMeter ? BANDWIDTH_METER : null,
//        buildHttpDataSourceFactory(useBandwidthMeter));
    return new DataSource.Factory() {
      @Override
      public DataSource createDataSource() {
        LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor evictor = new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(100 * 1024 * 1024);
        SimpleCache simpleCache = new SimpleCache(new File(getCacheDir(), "media_cache"), evictor);
        return new CacheDataSource(simpleCache, buildMyDataSourceFactory(useBandwidthMeter).createDataSource(),
                CacheDataSource.FLAG_BLOCK_ON_CACHE | CacheDataSource.FLAG_CACHE_UNBOUNDED_REQUESTS,
                10 * 1024 * 1024);
      }
    };
  }

  private DefaultDataSource.Factory buildMyDataSourceFactory(boolean useBandwidthMeter) {
    return new DefaultDataSourceFactory(PlayerActivity.this, userAgent, useBandwidthMeter ? BANDWIDTH_METER : null);
  }
```

Comment: I am using above code and able to cache the video but how to play video from cache ?