# Is it possible to use Glide to cache non-image files, such as videos and Lottie animations?

Tags: android, caching, android-glide, exoplayer, lottie

[**Glide**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) is a library used to load images in various ways, but I never saw an example of loading other kinds of contents, and passing it forward to other libraries.

As an example, I wonder if Glide could manage videos for [**ExoPlayer**](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) and JSON files for [**Lottie animations**](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android).

I tried to ask it on Glide's repository page ([**here**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3192)), but none told me if it's possible, and how .

We could have a cache for images, a cache for videos, and a cache for json files of Lottie, for example.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: No. Glide is meant to manage image, exoplayer does have its own cache mechanism. lottie too.

Comment: @GeorgePJ Are you sure about the caching of Lottie and Exoplayer? I don't see it anywhere. I'm talking about caching of actual files from URLs, like on Glide. Not caching within the current video/animation.

Answer (score 4):

For Lottie you need these 3 classes:

```
@GlideModule
class MedisafeGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {
    override fun registerComponents(
            context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        registry
                .register(LottieComposition::class.java, LottieDrawable::class.java, LottieDrawableTranscoder())
                .append(InputStream::class.java, LottieComposition::class.java, LottieDecoder())
    }

    override fun isManifestParsingEnabled() = false
}
```

Second one:

```
class LottieDecoder : ResourceDecoder<InputStream, LottieComposition> {

    override fun handles(source: InputStream, options: Options): Boolean = true

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun decode(source: InputStream, width: Int, height: Int, options: Options): Resource<LottieComposition> {
        return try {
            val lottieResult = LottieCompositionFactory.fromJsonInputStreamSync(source, null)
            SimpleResource(lottieResult.value!!)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            throw IOException("Cannot load lottie from stream", ex)
        }
    }
}
```

Third one:

```
class LottieDrawableTranscoder : ResourceTranscoder<LottieComposition, LottieDrawable> {
    override fun transcode(toTranscode: Resource<LottieComposition>, options: Options): Resource<LottieDrawable> {
        val composition = toTranscode.get()
        val lottieDrawable = LottieDrawable()
        lottieDrawable.composition = composition
        lottieDrawable.repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
        return SimpleResource(lottieDrawable)
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
Glide.with(imageView)
    .`as`(LottieDrawable::class.java)
    .load(url)
    .into(imageView)
```

Comment: Interesting. Sadly this was asked a long time ago so I can't test it. Have +1 for the effort though.

Comment: it works but animation is static, how to make the animation auto-play as soon as the LottieDrawable is set to the ImageView?

Comment: the issue is that I am using a `.transition(withCrossFade())` with it the image is not animated

Answer (score 1):

From Lottie Doc : http://airbnb.io/lottie/android/android.html#caching-animations

> **Caching Animations**
>
> by default. Default cache keys will be created for animations loaded
>   from res/raw/ or assets/. Other APIs require setting a cache key. If
>   you fire multiple animation requests for the same animation in
>   parallel such as a wishlist heart in a RecyclerView, subsequent
>   requests will join the existing task so it only gets parsed once
>   (Lottie >= 2.6.0).All Lottie animations are cached with a LRU cache

To know more about exoplayer cache please take a look at:

https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/pre-caching-downloading-progressive-streams-in-exoplayer-3a816c75e8f6

[Using cache in ExoPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700391/using-cache-in-exoplayer)

Comment: About Lottie, caching from built in animations within the app doesn't help here as it will cache things in memory alone (files already exist). I'm talking about caching in the way Glide can, from URLs. About ExoPlayer, can you please show an example of how to use it, here on StackOverflow?