# Number of valid fragments in application?

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

Is there any limitation in using of `fragments` in app? Can huge number of fragment s affect on performance of app?

**Edit**: I want to play movie with 5 minutes duration at most.

Comment: you can use same fragment to play different movies, 1 by 1 and yes, movies are quite heavy consumer

Comment: I use one fragment class but adapter returns maybe 500 number of this fragment.

Comment: that will just be a video item (item title and thumbnail) which is fine

Comment: + playing video

Comment: at a time only play visible list item's videos with considering a pause duration in scrolling

Comment: Yes just one. But if user swipes it saves current position of each playback and I think it should allocate a lot of memory.

Comment: use a threshold to avoid saving more than required, every problem comes with a solution (JNI, timestamp storage etc)

Comment: 500 fragments in one activity? you are not kidding?

Comment: 500 instance of one fragment. I'm serious.

Comment: and it depends on your data? what if you had 5000 items not 500? would you create 5000 instances of one fragment?

Comment: Yes, it depends. Adapter returns instances based on list size. Could you help swipe between movies in one activity?

Comment: ok, so are you aware of `RecyclerView` or `ListView` or similar widgets?

Comment: Do you know player can't be instantiated more than one? I release every player in `onStop()` callback of fragment. Is it possible to do this in `RecyclerView`?

Comment: player? what player? what actually do you want to achieve? you have a list of something (movies maybe) and ...?

Comment: Imagin instagram global search playing video automatically one by one. I want this. Every player in android should release. I use `exoplayer`.

Comment: and what do you need 500 fragments for?

Comment: To play videos.

Comment: no - to play video you dont need any fragment

Comment: So help me if you can. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any limitation in using of fragments in app?

There is no limit

> Can huge number of fragment affects on performance of app?

Yes, it surely can, reasons

- Memory allocations
- Cpu consuptions
- Lifecycle manager (activity and fragment both)

Possible Solution

- Enable large heap in manifest's application tag

  `android:largeHeap="true"`
- Use `findFragmentByTag` instead of creating fragments
- Use back stack

Comment: How much memory allocate with some player like `Exoplayer`? each fragment.

Comment: there is no exact calculation though it's depends upon the fragment class, number of members + video processing + exoplayer memory etc can be result into 100kb to (2-3) MB

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh How Using findFragmentByTag instead of creating fragments could help performance?

Comment: avoid creating new fragment in case of rotation etc!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any limitation in using of fragments in app?

**No**, there is no limit in adding fragments in Android development.

> Can huge number of fragment affects on performance of app?

its depend on  What operation you will perform in  fragments

Comment: Playing movie with 5 minute duration at most.

Comment: @SaminHeydarian where you are storing your `movies`

Comment: In First time fetch url path from server. But after that I want to use cache.

Comment: @SaminHeydarian and these movies are being played at same time? or do you release the media player after playing?

Comment: @SaminHeydarian check this [Using cache in ExoPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700391/using-cache-in-exoplayer)

Answer (score 0):

Using Fragments is dependent on App's functionality. 
It's Developer's Choisce to use Fragment's or not.
If your app contains various different options and you needed to use Navigation Drawer, TabView or any Swipable view then in such condition using Fragment will be more suitable.

Adding and Replacing Fragment in your app should done in correct manner and as per need. If it then it will not affect the performance of your app and there is no such limitation on certain number of using Fragments. You can add it as per your need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want to show a list of movies(maybe 500) in fragments and use pagination too. I think using fragment can help user to swipe and see movie easily. but I don't know how does it affects on performance of app.

Comment: For only seeing movie list you may or may not use the Fragment. You can do the same work simply in your Activity as well. I think here there is not need to take Fragment. If you are dealing with multiple options in same activity then you should take fragments in order to move or navigate from each other.

Comment: So can swipe in one activity?

Comment: Ya you can swipe in one Activity by using Tab Layout in an Activity. You can also use Viewpager for scrolling multiple fragments.

Comment: Both of `Tab layout` and `View pager` use fragment. And this is my problem.

Comment: Samin don't be messy. Please explain clearly what you want to do.

Comment: Imagin instagram global search playing video automatically one by one. I want this.

Comment: Put your own efforts first pls.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities.

The Fragment performing is important to get a good performance. Should handle right way like memory(cache,addBackStack,etc.,)

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Transactions