# Clear cache of exoplayer

Tags: android, caching, exoplayer

I have referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700391/using-cache-in-exoplayer?answertab=votes#tab-top) for creating `CachedDataSource` for Exo-Player and successfully created it, but I am not sure, how to delete the cache of the loaded video? 
There is a code example [here](https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/pre-caching-downloading-progressive-streams-in-exoplayer-3a816c75e8f6#a70c) , but I am not sure how to implement it.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

if you created a cache folder like it described in 
https://exoplayer.dev/downloading-media.html
example for kotlin

```
@Synchronized
fun getDownloadCache(): Cache {
    if (downloadCache == null) {
        val downloadContentDirectory = File(getDownloadDirectory(), DOWNLOAD_CONTENT_DIRECTORY)
        downloadCache = SimpleCache(downloadContentDirectory, NoOpCacheEvictor(), getDatabaseProvider())
    }
    return downloadCache as Cache
}
```

you can simply access this cache anywhere in your code to do this

```
fun clearCache() {
    application.getDownloadCache().release()
}
```

Or clean single key with this:

```
fun removeKeyFromCache(key: String) {
    CacheUtil.remove(application.getDownloadCache(), key)
}
```

application is an instance of your app, which can be created like this

```
lateinit var singleton: MyApp
open class MyApp: Application() {
  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    singleton = this
  }
}
```

And access it from anywhere:

```
private val application: MyApp = singleton
```

Comment: That's really helped me thanks but, I got confused with what the is `key` would be, but I found static fun will generate the key in `CacheUtil` :

`CacheUtil.generateKey(Uri.parse("www.test.com/1.mp3"))`

Answer (score 1):

it's working for me:

```
    public static void clearVideoCache(Context context){
        try {
            File dir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), cacheFolder);
            deleteDir(dir);
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    
    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return dir.delete();
        } else if(dir!= null && dir.isFile()) {
            return dir.delete();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

full code:

```
public class VideoCache {
    private static final String cacheFolder = "exoCache";
    private static SimpleCache sDownloadCache;

    public static SimpleCache getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sDownloadCache == null) sDownloadCache = new SimpleCache(new File(context.getCacheDir(), cacheFolder), new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(2000 * 1024 * 1024), new ExoDatabaseProvider(context));
        return sDownloadCache;
    }

    public static void clearVideoCache(Context context){
        try {
            File dir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), cacheFolder);
            deleteDir(dir);
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return dir.delete();
        } else if(dir!= null && dir.isFile()) {
            return dir.delete();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by accessing the directory where you save the cache, that way Do it in the OnDestroy method. I hope I help you

**JAVA**

```
 File file = new File(mContext.cacheDir, "NameFolder")
 file.delete()
```

**KOTLIN**

```
  val file = File(mContext.getCacheDir(), "NameFolder")
  file.delete()
```