# Offline viewing of HLS video using Exoplayer

Tags: exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am looking for sample code which shows how to download HLS video and play the downloaded video.

Comment: Hi...i also need this.Can some one please share  any sample code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41001057/2077869 See if this helps you! Its caching the video so it needs to play once before it can reload from cache.